# Jmeter , How to pass comma seperated multiple values in jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

Sometimes for same param I have to send multiple values ,Please find the details of the request below

GET Request with parameters

```
http://samplelink.com?name=john,mary,souds
http://samplelink.com?name=ram
http://samplelink.com?name=john,mary,souds,lakhan,jaby
```

How do I use this in jmeter at runtime to pick the values ? and what should be the file content of csv config.

Comment: can you collaborate bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), either by using double quotes:

> Meter allows values to be quoted; this allows the value to contain a delimiter. If "allow quoted data" is enabled, a value may be enclosed in double-quotes. These are removed. To include double-quotes within a quoted field, use two double-quotes. For example:
>
> `1,"2,3","4""5"`

Or use different delimiter as `@` to get values from CSV file:

> Delimiter Delimiter to be used to split the records in the file. If there are fewer values on the line than there are variables the remaining variables are not updated - so they will retain their previous value

For example file would be:

```
 1@2,3@4,5
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is going for [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function.

1. For example you have file `names.txt` in JMeter's "bin" folder with the following content in it:

   ```
   john,mary,souds
   ram
   john,mary,souds,lakhan,jaby
   ```
2. Once done you can just use __StringFromFile() function in the HTTP Request sampler "Path" field like:

   ```
   http://samplelink.com?name=${__StringFromFile(names.txt)}
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)